# ROS1 or ROS2? in Autonomous Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, mobile-robot

I am starting my thesis in Autonomous Navigation as a Mobile Robotics project, i am new to ROS and i need some advice on which one to choose between ROS1 or ROS2 to successful finish my thesis, and any other helpful advice is welcomed..

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 2):

You would need to provide much, much more information for anyone to make any kind of reasonable suggestion. But in general, ROS 2's navigation system is far more sophisticated than ROS 1's. If you want anything advanced and flexible, Nav2 is the answer. If you want something basic, ROS 1 is suitable.